# Limit of quotients implies limit of roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

If $a: \Bbb N\to (0, \infty)$ is a sequence with

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1} / a_n = L < \infty$, then it has to be shown that

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{1/n} = L$.

Has anybody a hint for me? I tried using the definition for convergence of sequences, but that did not work out.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

We have that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=L+b_n
$$
where $|b_n|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$.  This means that for every $n = N+m$, we can write
$$
a_n = \prod_{k=N}^{N+m-1}\left(L+b_k\right)a_N
$$

This product is between $(L-\epsilon)^{n-N}a_N$ and $(L+\epsilon)^{n-N}a_N$.   Taking the $n^{\text{th}}$ root of this product, we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}(L-\epsilon)^{\frac{n-N}{n}}a_N^{1/n}\leq
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n^{1/n}\leq
\lim_{n\to \infty}(L+\epsilon)^{\frac{n-N}{n}}a_N^{1/n}
$$

Certainly $a_N^{1/n}$ goes to $1$, so I just need to show that $(L-\epsilon)^{\frac{n-N}{n}}$ and $(L+\epsilon)^{\frac{n-N}{n}}$ go to $L-\epsilon$ and $L+\epsilon$, which is not hard.  Then, since, $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we get the desired result.